# Zooming Polygons: Can i know if the polygon borders are reaching the borders of the screen?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to show a square with the 100% of the width of the screen, then, i supose that i must zoom it (with Z axis) until the polygon borders are tounching the screen borders.

But how can i detect that?

Thanks

MySurfaceView

```
public class MySurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView implements Renderer {  
private Context context;
private Square square;
private float xrot;                 //X Rotation
private float yrot;                 //Y Rotation
private float zrot;                 //Z Rotation
private float xspeed;               //X Rotation Speed
private float yspeed;               //Y Rotation Speed
private float z = -1.15f;           //Profundidad en el eje Z
private float oldX; //valor anterior de X, para rotación
private float oldY; //valor anterior de Y, para rotación
private final float TOUCH_SCALE = 0.2f;     //necesario para la rotación

public MySurfaceView(Context context, Bitmap image) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0); //fondo transparente
    getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT); //fondo transparente
    //Transformamos esta clase en renderizadora
    this.setRenderer(this);
    //Request focus, para que los botones reaccionen
    this.requestFocus();
    this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    square = new Square(image);
}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {       
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);               //dithering OFF
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);            //Texture Mapping ON
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);            //Smooth Shading 
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);                     //Depth Buffer Setup
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);            //Depth Testing ON
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
    gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,0); //fondo transparente
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);         
    //Cargamos la textura del cubo.
    square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    //Limpiamos pantalla y Depth Buffer
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    //Dibujado
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, z);         //Move z units into the screen
    gl.glScalef(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f);          //Escalamos para que quepa en la pantalla
    //Rotamos sobre los ejes.
    gl.glRotatef(xrot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   //X
    gl.glRotatef(yrot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   //Y
    gl.glRotatef(zrot, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   //Z
    //Dibujamos el cuadrado
    square.draw(gl);    
    //Factores de rotación.
    xrot += xspeed;
    yrot += yspeed;
}

//si el surface cambia, resetea la vista, imagino que esto pasa cuando cambias de modo portrait/landscape o sacas el teclado físico en móviles tipo Droid.
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    if(height == 0) {                       
        height = 1;                         
    }
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);     //Reset Viewport
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    //Select Projection Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset Projection Matrix
    //Aspect Ratio de la ventana
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     //Select Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset Modelview Matrix
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) 
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //Calculamos el cambio
            float dx = x - oldX;
            float dy = y - oldY;
            xrot += dy * TOUCH_SCALE;
            yrot += dx * TOUCH_SCALE;
            //Log.w("XXXXXX", "ACTION_MOVE_NO_ZOOM");
            break;
    }
    oldX = x;
    oldY = y;
    return true; //El evento ha sido manejado
}

public void zoomIn(){ 
    z=z+0.2f;   
    if (z>-1.0f)
        z=-1.0f;
}
public void zoomOut(){ 
    z=z-0.2f; 
    if (z<-20.0f)
       z=-20.0f;
}
public void rotateL(){ 
    zrot=zrot+3.0f; 
}
public void rotateR(){ 
    zrot=zrot-3.0f; 
}   
public void reset()
{
    xrot=0;
    yrot=0;
    zrot=0;
    xspeed=0;
    yspeed=0;
    z = -5.0f;
}
}
```

Square class:

```
public class Square {
//Buffer de vertices
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
//Buffer de coordenadas de texturas
private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;
//Puntero de texturas
private int[] textures = new int[3];
//El item a representar
private Bitmap image;
//Definición de vertices

private float vertices[] = 
{ 
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,     //Bottom Left
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,      //Bottom Right
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,      //Top Left
    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f        //Top Right
};
/*  
private float vertices[] = 
{ 
-0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f,     //Bottom Left
0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f,      //Bottom Right
-0.8f, 0.8f, 0.0f,      //Top Left
0.8f, 0.8f, 0.0f 
};
*/
//Coordenadas (u, v) de las texturas    
/*
private float texture[] = 
{           
    //Mapping coordinates for the vertices
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f
};
*/
private float texture[] =
{
    //Mapping coordinates for the vertices
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f
};
//Inicializamos los buffers
public Square(Bitmap image) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
    byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
    textureBuffer.put(texture);
    textureBuffer.position(0);

    this.image=image;
} 
//Funcion de dibujado
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
    //gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    //Bind our only previously generated texture in this case
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    //Point to our vertex buffer
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);
    //Enable vertex buffer
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    //Draw the vertices as triangle strip
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);
    //Disable the client state before leaving
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    //gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);      
}
//Carga de texturas
public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {
    //Generamos un puntero de texturas
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);       
    //y se lo asignamos a nuestro array
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    //Creamos filtros de texturas
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    //Diferentes parametros de textura posibles GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);     
    /*
    String imagePath = "radiocd5.png";
    AssetManager mngr = context.getAssets();
    InputStream is=null;
    try {
        is = mngr.open(imagePath);
    } catch (IOException e1) {  e1.printStackTrace();   }
    */
    //Get the texture from the Android resource directory
    InputStream is=null;
    /*
    if (item.equals("rim"))
        is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.rueda);
    else if (item.equals("selector"))
        is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.selector);
    */      
    /*
    is = context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
            is = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    */
    Bitmap bitmap =image;       
    //con el siguiente código redimensionamos las imágenes que sean mas grandes de 256x256.
    int newW=bitmap.getWidth();
    int newH=bitmap.getHeight();
    float fact;
    if (newH>256 || newW>256)
    {
        if (newH>256)
        {
            fact=(float)255/(float)newH; //porcentaje por el que multiplicar para ser tamaño 256
            newH=(int)(newH*fact); //altura reducida al porcentaje necesario
            newW=(int)(newW*fact); //anchura reducida al porcentaje necesario   
        }
        if (newW>256)
        {
            fact=(float)255/(float)newW; //porcentaje por el que multiplicar para ser tamaño 256
            newH=(int)(newH*fact); //altura reducida al porcentaje necesario
            newW=(int)(newW*fact); //anchura reducida al porcentaje necesario
        }
        bitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newW, newH, true);
    }       
    //con el siguiente código transformamos imágenes no potencia de 2 en imágenes potencia de 2 (pot)
    //meto el bitmap NOPOT en un bitmap POT para que no aparezcan texturas blancas.
    int nextPot=256;
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();
    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int offx=(nextPot-w)/2; //distancia respecto a la izquierda, para que la imagen quede centrada en la nueva imagen POT
    int offy=(nextPot-h)/2; //distancia respecto a arriba, para que la imagen quede centrada en la nueva imagen POT
    Bitmap bitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(nextPot, nextPot, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); //crea un bitmap transparente gracias al ARGB_8888
    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(bitmap2);
    comboImage.drawBitmap(bitmap, offx, offy, null);
    comboImage.save();

    //Usamos Android GLUtils para espcificar una textura de 2 dimensiones para nuestro bitmap
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap2, 0);

    //Checkeamos si el GL context es versión 1.1 y generamos los Mipmaps por Flag. Si no, llamamos a nuestra propia implementación
    if(gl instanceof GL11) {
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL11.GL_TRUE);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap2, 0);
    } else {
        buildMipmap(gl, bitmap2);
    }   
    //Limpiamos los bitmaps
    bitmap.recycle();
    bitmap2.recycle();
}
//Nuestra implementación de MipMap. Escalamos el bitmap original hacia abajo por factor de 2 y lo asignamos como nuevo nivel de mipmap
private void buildMipmap(GL10 gl, Bitmap bitmap) {
    int level = 0;
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    while(height >= 1 || width >= 1) {
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, level, bitmap, 0);
        if(height == 1 || width == 1) {
            break;
        }
        level++;
        height /= 2;
        width /= 2;
        Bitmap bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
        bitmap.recycle();
        bitmap = bitmap2;
    }
}
}
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
/////////////// NEW CODE FOR SCALING THE AR IMAGE TO THE DESIRED WIDTH /////////////////

        //and them, call the getCurrentModelView() for the ModelView matrix:  
        mg.getCurrentModelView(gl);  
        //values are stored at the mg.mModelView array, so:  
        //Log.i("Translation Z value", Float.toString(mg.mModelView[14]));//prints the current translation z value            
        //to get the current Projection matrix:  
        mg.getCurrentProjection(gl);  
        //values are stored at the mProjection, so:  
        //Log.i("First projection matrix value", Float.toString(mg.mProjection[0]));//prints the first projection matrix value 

        float [] modelMatrix = new float[16];
        float [] projMatrix = new float[16];        
        modelMatrix=mg.mModelView;
        projMatrix=mg.mProjection;
        // Now I am going to assume you set the model and projection matrices correctly
        // so I won't show that here.
        int [] mView = new int[4];
        // Fill this with your window width and height
        mView[0] = 0;
        mView[1] = 0;
        mView[2] = 800; //width
        mView[3] = 480; //height
        // Make sure you have 3 components in this array even if the screen only needs 2
        float [] outputCoords = new float[3];
        // Now I also assume that objX, objY, objZ are the coordinates of one of your borders
        GLU.gluProject(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, modelMatrix, 0, projMatrix, 0, mView, 0, outputCoords, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use gluProject to project a coordinate in 3D into a 2D screen coordinate. If the screen coordinate is either 0 or matches either your width or height, then it is touching a screen border.

**Edit for more information:**

Look at the definition on : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLU.html.
Basically you pass it the three coordinates of your vertex as objX objY objZ. You also pass it your modelview matrix and projection matrix, and your view as a float array which contains the window size. And then you get the resulting window coordinates in the win variable. Here is a quick example:

```
float [] modelMatrix = new float[16];
float [] projMatrix = new float[16];

// Now I am going to assume you set the model and projection matrices correctly
// so I won't show that here.

float [] mView = new float[4];
// Fill this with your window width and height
view[0] = 0;
view[1] = 0;
view[2] = width;
view[3] = height;

// Make sure you have 3 components in this array even if the screen only needs 2
float [] outputCoords = new float[3]

// Now I also assume that objX, objY, objZ are the coordinates of one of your borders
gluProject(objX, objY, objZ, modelMatrix, 0, projMatrix, 0, view, 0, outputCoords, 0);
```

You will also need to keep track of your matrices since some versions of opengl for android do not do this. See the example here for matrix tracking : http://www.41post.com/1540/programming/android-opengl-get-the-modelview-matrix-on-15-cupcake

Comment: can you explain it a little more please? maybe with a tinny code example? my skills with OpenGl are just newbie skills, i'm trying to find examples on google for doing what u mean but i can't find them

Comment: THanks for the update, where i have to do that code, on the square class? or on the MyGLsurfaceVIew class?

Comment: I don't know how your code is structured so I have no idea where it should go.

Comment: I edited my code to add the two classes, definitively i dont know how to implement your code on my classes, i dont have the modelMatrix, the projMatrix and dont know how to find the other parameters for the gluProject function :(

Comment: Just looking quickly at what you posted, you could put it in your onTouchEvent method. As for the modelMatrix and projMatrix, you do set them in onSurfaceChanged. Just make sure you can grab them in your onTouchEvent method by referring to the matrix tracking code i linked in my answer.

Comment: ok, with that code i can obtain the projection matrix, but not the objx objy and objz values, how to obtain these four things? Also, i have to supose that "mg.mModelView" is the modelMatrix?

Comment: Yes and the obj values would be your vertex coordinates.

Comment: Nick, something is going wrong, please tell me if i am doing something wrong, i updated my question with the new code. The outputCoords array is giving me these values: 0,0,0.5    :S i dont understand these values :S

Comment: The code is on the onSurfaceCreated method of the GLSurfaceView class, ¿it have to be putted in another method? ¿where? I cant put it on the ontouch, because i need the gl variable accesible.

Comment: Did you use the matrix grabber AND wrap the opengl implementation? If you did not wrap the opengl with the classes from the website I gave then the matrix grabber will not be able to see your modelMatrix and projectionMatrix. An easy way to see that is to look at the model and projection matrices just before you pass them to gluProject. If they are all zeros, then you have not successfully wrapped opengl.